# Bad response from idP in Auth Code Exchange during google account linking with Rails and DialogFlow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to build a rails app as backend for custom Google Actions. The rough user flow would be for users of my app to invoke my custom action via "talk to *my_action*", which would require them to sign in. From there, i could proceed with extracting user info from their google accounts. The problem i'm facing right now is during the account linking process.

So, the current flow is as such:

> 'talk to *my_action*' >> user prompted to view Google Home app to link accounts >> user clicks on the link to link their accounts >> redirected to page where they choose user accounts/ sign in with google account >> '*Bad response from IdP in Auth Code Exchange*'. I've searched high and low regarding this error message but i could only find one regarding this specific message.

(I'm unable to post the screenshot due to lack of reputation sorry! But essentially the error screen is just `*Bad response from IdP in Auth Code Exchange*` and a link to `*Re-run linking flow*` which still doesn't work.)

Currently, I'm using the gem `'omniauth-google-oauth2'` to authenticate with Google via OAuth2 in OmniAuth. I'm not too sure about the omniauth part, but the oauth auth code exchange should take place as described in [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

I am also using the gem `google_assistant`, specifically the assistant-api-v2 branch. This gem hasn't been updated in a while, and might not have been extensively used/tested, so this might be a potential cause. My server is hosted on heroku, and i use DialogFlow as the fulfilment tool. In DialogFlow, i've already enabled webhooks to my app `/myapp/google_assistant`, and i've ticked the `Sign-In Required` checkbox.

As for my accounts linking settings in the Actions on Google Dashboard, i've

> 1. Set the linking type to be only Oauth, and grant type to be implicit.
> 2. Set the Client ID as my oauth2 client ID
> 3. Authorization URL as '*my-app.com/users/auth/google_oauth2*' (Token url not required)
> 4. Set scope as gmail
> 5. Set testing information as 'username: test@email.com, password: password'. I do not know what is the proper format for this field yet.

The logs on my Heroku web-app server during the linking process are as follows:

```
2018-07-05T10:44:16.955840 #4]  INFO -- : [a5b63d61-d97d-4b04-a10b-b3fee18c1c7d] Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2?response_type=token&client_id=*my_client_id*&redirect_uri=https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/*my_project_id*&scope=https://mail.google.com/&state=AA7-RQxyASRZMH3DU8v1lXOx08dXZdlDa_8qIqoQfcdSdbT2ltPpyO4JVYGo7SZWmCLgu2oq1aPnojP_ygDQQgjH-3fz7EFopdKVl1WqABA_uhSfwxGqN5ywmLXWE-Y74AFMTs4sEVkG_ctUxCz7oMXDumdPELRjHlhO0VRhcJXQFhCZ_2OOrEDKkST-pPLy_cD4T2Pptni9JQj8QUeXYkklg1I-836q4zqt6vOA9mCEEFqS_h0hwaVizBypk8joO85dOibe8w4OYlp4BHDegSQ_97oPeHJu_7TSJg9M2fAyZqww0XDNjwQAFCwFR1Z0fZ3b4RySlG5Uy_yLr_F5wLbMLvLa0mX63mwuf3hOUX4zoCpBoMnBcLi7hFUiaPj1wpTBhmrAZ05Oq6jKRcOqC-FX6yERPl5tQvNdsGdjH63mc-4J3tDL0tUzvvkYm6p0CjuOho4GiQwA1XZGvHZmOcKPLA6CKr26THAXmPVJSQmiIH1CSAuAypguuiNy0yhmMKgTH_WH5M8banpYYob-Yv2jVqu2H5f2RjF0i_XApCcHUj6VoNEg0cFYiMYaiIKJRH20-HpymW3IgOEd_2TjPg5yKEbYN5bN7C-zILVLC_1qyofyze0ag0lxgvsx3kvbAEI1MLpVAF0EACZeHJujzb8YM0vmOB8FuQLOeSanyZ8zrwrWXRzu9hSBQ4eHegsSneb5CugcQkt09uSnQhOTGGwOi0TVk_f6Sw" for *my_ip* at 2018-07-05 10:44:16 +0000

2018-07-05T10:44:16.956747+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-07-05T10:44:16.956679 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.

2018-07-05T10:44:17.015111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/users/auth/google_oauth2?response_type=token&client_id=*my-client-id*&redirect_uri=https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/my-project-id&scope=https://mail.google.com/&state=AA7-RQxyASRZMH3DU8v1lXOx08dXZdlDa_8qIqoQfcdSdbT2ltPpyO4JVYGo7SZWmCLgu2oq1aPnojP_ygDQQgjH-3fz7EFopdKVl1WqABA_uhSfwxGqN5ywmLXWE-Y74AFMTs4sEVkG_ctUxCz7oMXDumdPELRjHlhO0VRhcJXQFhCZ_2OOrEDKkST-pPLy_cD4T2Pptni9JQj8QUeXYkklg1I-836q4zqt6vOA9mCEEFqS_h0hwaVizBypk8joO85dOibe8w4OYlp4BHDegSQ_97oPeHJu_7TSJg9M2fAyZqww0XDNjwQAFCwFR1Z0fZ3b4RySlG5Uy_yLr_F5wLbMLvLa0mX63mwuf3hOUX4zoCpBoMnBcLi7hFUiaPj1wpTBhmrAZ05Oq6jKRcOqC-FX6yERPl5tQvNdsGdjH63mc-4J3tDL0tUzvvkYm6p0CjuOho4GiQwA1XZGvHZmOcKPLA6CKr26THAXmPVJSQmiIH1CSAuAypguuiNy0yhmMKgTH_WH5M8banpYYob-Yv2jVqu2H5f2RjF0i_XApCcHUj6VoNEg0cFYiMYaiIKJRH20-HpymW3IgOEd_2TjPg5yKEbYN5bN7C-zILVLC_1qyofyze0ag0lxgvsx3kvbAEI1MLpVAF0EACZeHJujzb8YM0vmOB8FuQLOeSanyZ8zrwrWXRzu9hSBQ4eHegsSneb5CugcQkt09uSnQhOTGGwOi0TVk_f6Sw" host=*my-web-app* request_id=a5b63d61-d97d-4b04-a10b-b3fee18c1c7d fwd="*my-ip*" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=63ms status=302 bytes=5935 protocol=https
```

As for the redirect chain of the process, i'm not sure how to entirely save the network logs, but using a Chrome extension, the redirect-chain when signing in to google account, leading to the bad response error is:

```
Status Code URL IP  Page Type   Redirect Type   Redirect URL    
302 https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/*my-project-id*?state=AA7-RQyd1KsD63DBoQF_-NfYijzGvptfXTEj8D3AwQzW_ByUe8K0UnLZVuQjE6y8txJMcabFTC4fQhxHqqpTv28_e3dDuLBpYaGKqo_urwHkswmf1pAV2da7nPoVb-n1DHe1P-xU-jzU5c8vlyWCXJPpMDZyR7K0AQ7qdDCQRtr9oPpDymPyYknGIrQB6rI9VRSFinsGhZTnno2AvtOJCkTZfe3abYSdzjB-Am3PI9p-oAwh0f6mBzUGDYCMIB-traI_INV9fSa8tS9K363pBKUBQ-YgKI5nKI8Uqbz5UduNDwB99eQSUaEZu48vabVTwGjsLUczbkA46-u-AKAV65iwTPE6e-zRI11LRgfw4uObam8S3xvL3ok9pESzwGpMlBmEO0goyg9xJa2ULatLOy2PGRcMbWcuhyp84ttzedmiD2gdidVxHafEwgSpSEqad6YLWvCtV4XGbHxyuFZXF8rjFiDUK__KaJ2G-cbzyiXaVQ-YOh80NM8QQmAIPvys-2BTteP_G-1xjRZFpgJO6-dnZw2jelcF8KkITIGTNMuLejrcCyADjusaNOMrHMkASXohnq5p0lpkjPIcEZryghziPu3soPJ8A9jj8K9Ka-CWNosv9aBAnpN4eKYlOBEVljc6W824XPYgYMW62cBHlTlqV8RMNpo_5h6LRf2UdmY2T85xk3Iuz1_1Lr8jeu-UYZILPP2sc7HrjP7eFp70qgMCUQEk_JwsyQ&code=4/AAC6qctB8IxI0ijzYibSubvzae-yNgNcVOtUrbnhORSMNRxQXi2DeZE9wqn6lLqOLkb0NYeYRU15IH8H6qP9CcY# 172.217.160.1   server_redirect temporary   https://gala-demo.appspot.com/app#redirect_state=AA7-RQxBXe_JzFx7iXtcObVa7AJ4qPiiLY_XHrtgX861Z1TlUiOLFM3ymhzxqHWCONLFXjOJQkhNyCsH35cylVBrKtyLDaE-4J7wJ-P9PS3-JEPVeaoRnm7uo4ncLPW5EMxR--onGLFNZydFbqNKhdhWTox3FkUuv2lNZB2FcY9ZuhmE7LwiMXFYatawmFXpjZ0QdLkKEvqGcrG0gxi6G9e_Rsa1maUBWLvb3GKU3jXfL5J0YQI_Y6WwJj5c1c8gzBnABulzSR9wak3r9J-wTSM1-doKNIWr1OBeeoj40AR-NwIcj_9BgOGupUTQA-jdV0mQL6q69bVDuwrMJ_ftuC2ojAINWuGcVlF8MaT8phT347rFS8jAfZXKMM2N6gwEbO6Pepgtndg74JcKcwN6jhN0_dWE9XnNH78iwZoQP2nIu1_hojLOiN26-Y3l1xjKUu9WpCrdbIn3jdBIjUs_82pwM2uRqdvLAuiJJVktaJ9CNaky29bihLV1KwcyzQU5zMZ0YdOgvDi7vDHF15FyR2mlywXhx2Pzqs_Gi09Q3CUQ_u0JKiM3_Iyo9RxuzDUZIvZRUtGbu4W2rIWHgKuwGEw6C611ZGtUjORNpEjgHc_861OLJJBSqAIqGgE1tvilyV9y6FbqoXtP5bAfYFuWWl5lmcy9r6s3D3coagPdKlHcrxYxkUETRSyuaCcBo75ilztd3YqgyxVIadbgOwHmU0Cx-mtdwwJOfEdousw2dXnAkdVuG1d4fv6dT6XKyd4x7dyh7CPtVH9O2j65NvIqFE90NfQdNupm_kSKfnt3xCnwzTv155BM4B9tiXd6aKp3d2xIkY57nsTqOTBmTZ6_lf9-EWeHxS_0ukbDYiSVQsFwDz8d0GilKeU&state=AA7-RQyd1KsD63DBoQF_-NfYijzGvptfXTEj8D3AwQzW_ByUe8K0UnLZVuQjE6y8txJMcabFTC4fQhxHqqpTv28_e3dDuLBpYaGKqo_urwHkswmf1pAV2da7nPoVb-n1DHe1P-xU-jzU5c8vlyWCXJPpMDZyR7K0AQ7qdDCQRtr9oPpDymPyYknGIrQB6rI9VRSFinsGhZTnno2AvtOJCkTZfe3abYSdzjB-Am3PI9p-oAwh0f6mBzUGDYCMIB-traI_INV9fSa8tS9K363pBKUBQ-YgKI5nKI8Uqbz5UduNDwB99eQSUaEZu48vabVTwGjsLUczbkA46-u-AKAV65iwTPE6e-zRI11LRgfw4uObam8S3xvL3ok9pESzwGpMlBmEO0goyg9xJa2ULatLOy2PGRcMbWcuhyp84ttzedmiD2gdidVxHafEwgSpSEqad6YLWvCtV4XGbHxyuFZXF8rjFiDUK__KaJ2G-cbzyiXaVQ-YOh80NM8QQmAIPvys-2BTteP_G-1xjRZFpgJO6-dnZw2jelcF8KkITIGTNMuLejrcCyADjusaNOMrHMkASXohnq5p0lpkjPIcEZryghziPu3soPJ8A9jj8K9Ka-CWNosv9aBAnpN4eKYlOBEVljc6W824XPYgYMW62cBHlTlqV8RMNpo_5h6LRf2UdmY2T85xk3Iuz1_1Lr8jeu-UYZILPP2sc7HrjP7eFp70qgMCUQEk_JwsyQ&service=*my_project_id*dev

200 https://gala-demo.appspot.com/app#redirect_state=AA7-RQxBXe_JzFx7iXtcObVa7AJ4qPiiLY_XHrtgX861Z1TlUiOLFM3ymhzxqHWCONLFXjOJQkhNyCsH35cylVBrKtyLDaE-4J7wJ-P9PS3-JEPVeaoRnm7uo4ncLPW5EMxR--onGLFNZydFbqNKhdhWTox3FkUuv2lNZB2FcY9ZuhmE7LwiMXFYatawmFXpjZ0QdLkKEvqGcrG0gxi6G9e_Rsa1maUBWLvb3GKU3jXfL5J0YQI_Y6WwJj5c1c8gzBnABulzSR9wak3r9J-wTSM1-doKNIWr1OBeeoj40AR-NwIcj_9BgOGupUTQA-jdV0mQL6q69bVDuwrMJ_ftuC2ojAINWuGcVlF8MaT8phT347rFS8jAfZXKMM2N6gwEbO6Pepgtndg74JcKcwN6jhN0_dWE9XnNH78iwZoQP2nIu1_hojLOiN26-Y3l1xjKUu9WpCrdbIn3jdBIjUs_82pwM2uRqdvLAuiJJVktaJ9CNaky29bihLV1KwcyzQU5zMZ0YdOgvDi7vDHF15FyR2mlywXhx2Pzqs_Gi09Q3CUQ_u0JKiM3_Iyo9RxuzDUZIvZRUtGbu4W2rIWHgKuwGEw6C611ZGtUjORNpEjgHc_861OLJJBSqAIqGgE1tvilyV9y6FbqoXtP5bAfYFuWWl5lmcy9r6s3D3coagPdKlHcrxYxkUETRSyuaCcBo75ilztd3YqgyxVIadbgOwHmU0Cx-mtdwwJOfEdousw2dXnAkdVuG1d4fv6dT6XKyd4x7dyh7CPtVH9O2j65NvIqFE90NfQdNupm_kSKfnt3xCnwzTv155BM4B9tiXd6aKp3d2xIkY57nsTqOTBmTZ6_lf9-EWeHxS_0ukbDYiSVQsFwDz8d0GilKeU&state=AA7-RQyd1KsD63DBoQF_-NfYijzGvptfXTEj8D3AwQzW_ByUe8K0UnLZVuQjE6y8txJMcabFTC4fQhxHqqpTv28_e3dDuLBpYaGKqo_urwHkswmf1pAV2da7nPoVb-n1DHe1P-xU-jzU5c8vlyWCXJPpMDZyR7K0AQ7qdDCQRtr9oPpDymPyYknGIrQB6rI9VRSFinsGhZTnno2AvtOJCkTZfe3abYSdzjB-Am3PI9p-oAwh0f6mBzUGDYCMIB-traI_INV9fSa8tS9K363pBKUBQ-YgKI5nKI8Uqbz5UduNDwB99eQSUaEZu48vabVTwGjsLUczbkA46-u-AKAV65iwTPE6e-zRI11LRgfw4uObam8S3xvL3ok9pESzwGpMlBmEO0goyg9xJa2ULatLOy2PGRcMbWcuhyp84ttzedmiD2gdidVxHafEwgSpSEqad6YLWvCtV4XGbHxyuFZXF8rjFiDUK__KaJ2G-cbzyiXaVQ-YOh80NM8QQmAIPvys-2BTteP_G-1xjRZFpgJO6-dnZw2jelcF8KkITIGTNMuLejrcCyADjusaNOMrHMkASXohnq5p0lpkjPIcEZryghziPu3soPJ8A9jj8K9Ka-CWNosv9aBAnpN4eKYlOBEVljc6W824XPYgYMW62cBHlTlqV8RMNpo_5h6LRf2UdmY2T85xk3Iuz1_1Lr8jeu-UYZILPP2sc7HrjP7eFp70qgMCUQEk_JwsyQ&service=*my_project_id*_dev   74.125.24.153   normal  none    none
```

I also noticed that there's a single error 400 during the last step of authentication:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad response from IdP in Auth Code Exchange",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}

    Request URL: https://oauthintegrations.googleapis.com/v1/token:getForService
    Request Method: POST
    Status Code: 400
    Remote Address: 74.125.24.95:443
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    access-control-allow-origin: https://gala-demo.appspot.com
    access-control-expose-headers: content-encoding,date,server,content-length
    alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35"
    cache-control: private
    content-encoding: gzip
    content-length: 136
    content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    date: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 13:17:41 GMT
    server: ESF
    status: 400
    vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
    x-content-type-options: nosniff
    x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
    x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    Provisional headers are shown
    Authorization: Bearer *my access_token*
    Content-Type: application/json
    Origin: https://gala-demo.appspot.com
    Referer: https://gala-demo.appspot.com/app
    User-Agent: *my user agent*
    {credential: {,…}, gdiState: "APP_AUTH", serviceId: "ardent-fusion-209108_dev",…}
    credential
    :
    {,…}
    gdiState
    :
    "APP_AUTH"
    scopes
    :
    ["https://mail.google.com/"]
    serviceId
    :
    "*my_project_id*_dev"
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Please do comment if you need any more information. Thanks and have a nice day! :)

**Updates**: I've since realized that omniauth follows the auth code flow. I've thus changed my linking flow to auth code and added `/users/auth/google_oauth2` as my auth url and `/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback` as my token url. However, there is now an error of redirect_uri_mismatch even though i have added `my_app.com/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback` and `my_app.com/users/auth/google_oauth2` and `oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/my_proj_id` into my oauth client's authorized uri redirects. I've since tried adding a trailing / to the redirect uri in the client, as well as swapping https for http and adding a www in front of each uri, but all of these methods don't work. (All urls above are with https; my reputation is too low to post more than 8 links so i have to omit them)

The new errors logs are as such:

```
2018-07-06T10:06:48.542310+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-07-06T10:06:48.542182 #4]  INFO -- : [2270a384-f7a5-4b6a-9dce-a6999dc47b28] Started POST "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback/" for 66.249.83.158 at 2018-07-06 10:06:48 +0000

2018-07-06T10:06:48.542796+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-07-06T10:06:48.542726 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.

2018-07-06T10:06:48.651257+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2018-07-06T10:06:48.651082 #4] ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, redirect_uri_mismatch: Bad Request

2018-07-06T10:06:48.651261+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2018-07-06T10:06:48.651264+00:00 app[web.1]:   "error" : "redirect_uri_mismatch",
2018-07-06T10:06:48.651266+00:00 app[web.1]:   "error_description" : "Bad Request"
2018-07-06T10:06:48.651268+00:00 app[web.1]: }

2018-07-06T10:06:48.652619+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-07-06T10:06:48.652524 #4]  INFO -- : [2270a384-f7a5-4b6a-9dce-a6999dc47b28] Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as JSON

2018-07-06T10:06:48.652781+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-07-06T10:06:48.652696 #4]  INFO -- : [2270a384-f7a5-4b6a-9dce-a6999dc47b28]   Parameters: {"grant_type"=>"authorization_code", "code"=>"*my_auth_code*", "redirect_uri"=>"https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/*my_proj_id*", "client_id"=>"*my_client_id*", "client_secret"=>"*my_client_secret*"}
```

Comment: You indicated you set the link type to "oauth2". On the same screen in the Action Console, what did you set the Grant Type to? You say you set the Authorization URL, but did you set the Token URL? (Updating the question with your answers is better than posting the answer here - just let us know when you do update. And going through the tutorial to get reputation should get you enough to post images, which may be helpful.)

Comment: @Prisoner i've updated my question with the points in your question thanks!

Comment: That helps greatly. What OAuth server are you using and do you have any logs from it that you can add to the question?

Comment: @Prisoner sorry but i don't exactly know what you mean by which oauth server i'm using. If you're referring to my web-app server then it's heroku, and i updated my question to have the logs during which the authentication happens. Sorry i'm still a real beginner at this!

Comment: No need to apologize - OAuth and security can be tricky. These logs are useful - it sounds like you're using OmniAuth to handle the authentication? I'm not familiar with it (or ruby very much), so updating the question with information about how you're using it and how you have it configured to generate the access token will help. In the last entry you show, it looks like it is doing an http redirect, which is expected, although it would be very useful to know where it is redirecting to. Browser logs showing the redirect chain, ending with the redirect to Google, would be useful.

Comment: @Prisoner I've updated my post with more logs!

Comment: Did you got the answer? @ChiahSoon

Comment: @Rajesh It's been a while but take a look at the Doorkeeper gem for rails! I used it to implement Oauth functionality in my rails app so that i can authenticate google services on my heroku server

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what is going wrong and, rather than trying to fix it, a completely different approach to the problem which should hopefully work better.

**What is going wrong (and some background)**

Traditional authentication with Actions on Google required you to setup an OAuth server. When the user gets to a point in their Action where you require an authenticated user, it directs them to your OAuth web server to login, expects your server to send an access token or auth code back to it, possibly do some further work to get an auth token, and then send you the access or auth token every time your webhook fulfillment is called. You then use this token to figure out who the user is and act appropriately.

What looks like is happening is that the Assistant is sending the user to your login point with information that says "when you're done, redirect back here with an access token". That part seems fine. You're going through a login process that includes Google Sign In. At some point in there, you're redirecting back to the same URL the Assistant wants.

The problem is that instead of sending back an access token, it is sending a one time auth code. The Assistant gets this and, since it isn't what it is configured to handle, bails out with an error.

It isn't clear why it is sending the code instead of the access token. It could be that OmniAuth is designed to use the "auth code" method, and you've configured the Assistant to use the "implicit" method. Or it could be that both the Sign In and Assistant are using the same URL as part of the process, and this is confusing things. OR it could be that OmniAuth isn't really meant to play the role of an OAuth server.

If you really want to go this route, investigate the OmniAuth configuration and consider changing its or the Action's configuration.

***Update***: Sounds like it was using the incorrect auth flow, and I'm glad you've straightened that out. The authorized redirect_uri that you should be setting for OmniAuth needs to be *exactly* what Google is sending as part of its request: `https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/my_project_id`

However... you may not need this.

**Using Google Sign-In for Account Linking**

Since you are signing in the user in your webapp using Google Sign-In, you may be able to avoid the entire OAuth server issue and take advantage of a shortcut that is now available. If your webapp and your Action are both part of the same Google Cloud Project, then [Google Sign In for the Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in) will send you an ID Token for the user once they have authenticated themselves to the project. They can authenticate themselves either through voice in the Action or by logging into a webapp with Google Sign In.

The ID Token that is sent is not an auth token. However, if you have saved the auth token and refresh token from the user logging into your webapp, you can use the information in the ID Token to look this information up and use them.

The big "gotcha" as part of this is that you need to request the additional scopes only through your webapp - there is no way to do this as part of the Action. This isn't a major hurdle, however - it just means that if a user reaches your Action without an ID, direct them to log into your webapp first.

See further discussion and diagrams [at this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50932537/1405634)

Comment: Thanks for such a in-depth explanation! I've done somemore research into the topic and i found that omniauth uses the auth code flow instead of the implicit flow. I've hence updated the question as I've ran into another error.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but i've already copied and pasted the exact url into my oauth client page, however the issue persists. One thing is that instead of going to the typical uri mismatch google page in the browser, the redirect uri mismatch error only shows in heroku logs, and on the the google page it shows the same bad request error. I've ensured that the redirect uri parameters in the logs are the exact same as the one i've put into my oauth client, so i'm really stumped as to why this error still occurs.

Comment: Showing the heroku logs for this would be useful, but having them there makes sense - this is an OmniAuth configuration issue.

Comment: Hmm so this redirect uri mismatch might possibly be an error on omniauth’s part? Ive added the logs btw!

Comment: This is certainly something inside OmniAuth. I don't know if it is an error, or if your OmniAuth configuration is just incorrect - you haven't shown the OmniAuth configuration (and I don't know enough about OmniAuth to know how to configure it).

Comment: Just wanna come back and let you know that i've found out that my understanding of account linking was completely wrong LOL i initially thought that it was authenticating my service to Google, but turns out to be the other way around. I've thus found a way for my app to have a oauth functionality, and was successful in linking accounts. Thanks alot for pointing me in the right direction though!

Comment: How you did the authentication? I'm hitting with same issue.

Comment: @Rajesh - if you're having similar problems and don't see an answer, go ahead and post your own with as many details as you can provide for people to help. As they indicated - they were trying to do something that couldn't be done, but found the documentation pointed them to the right way to do it.