# I want to connect DialogFlow to Google SpreadSheet

Tags: node.js, api, dialogflow-es, google-sheets-api

I was going to send the info obtained from dialogflow bot to my google spreadsheet to save and reuse them.
I tried use fullfillment in DialogFlow. I logged in SheetSu which provides the API for google spreadsheet and got API from that site(sheetsu.com).
and then i'm embarrased with that API in fullullment in DialogFlow.
Is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) directly. This will likely require you to go through [Google Sign In for Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50932537/1405634) to get an access/refresh token.

(If you just want voice commands for Sheets, Actions such as [Vodo Drive](https://vodo-drive.com/) are working on the issue.)