# Dialogflow account linking with Node JS application

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, account-linking

I am new to Dialogflow. I want to do an account linking with my node js application. So when I click on signin button in simulator, popup is opening with the request below

```
Request URL : https://dialogflow.herokuapp.com/login
response_type : code
client_id: da4sad4sa56ds54sdb67re5a4
redirect_uri: https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/myprojectid
scope : openid+_offlineaccess+profile+email
state: AKLMQkUP19DCPvMBboadq7rgpSPrsDPT1fTXnWT-8_mVK
```

with the above payload, once use enters credentials validating the user with DB, here how to perform redirect to dialogflow requested intent with an authorization token in node js. Please suggest
[image]
After clicking on the sign in the simulator and accepting for the linking it is showing the login popup after successful login wants to redirect back to the simulator with response.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear - when you say "Account Linking" are you talking about Actions on Google, or are you talking about something else? What is it doing that you're not expecting?

Comment: Yes. I mean actions on google. I want to redirect to dialogflow with the response after validating at node js application

Comment: Can you update your question to show pictures of what you are trying to do and what it isn't doing?

Comment: hey @Prisoner I read your answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185196/implementing-account-linking-queries I think I got some clarification for what I am doing. First I have to set up oAuth server hope this flow works fine after that. Thanks